# How to define global hooks in TestCafe using TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

In [documentation](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402638/reference/configuration-file#javascript) it is recommended to use js configuration file in order to define a global hook, however this is a problem for TypeScript solution.

I wasn't able to use my TS classes/functions in .js configuration file and it doesn't seem to be possible to create a .ts configuration file.

So my question is, **how am I supposed to use global hooks with TS**, when I can't reference my own code.
Is this a mistake on my part or it is simply issue of TestCafe not having support for .ts config file yet.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please share more detailed information about your use case? Do you want to import classes or functions from `*.ts` files and use them or use TS in the config file?

Comment: I have my whole solution in .ts, so I am either looking for a viable way of using my TS classes and functions in .js config file. Or a posibility of having a .ts config file.

Basically what are people, that adapted testcafe in typescript, supposed to do to properly use global hooks (as currently it seems I can't really combine js config and my own ts code).

Comment: TestCafe doesn't support TS config. Please create an enhancement request with [this template](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?assignees=&labels=TYPE%3A+enhancement&template=feature_request.yaml/) for your suggestion.
Now you can request simple TS files to the config file but it isn't a feature and it is not reliable, since it may be changed in the future.